# npm install --save solc on Atom

Tags: npm, npm-install, atom-editor, solidity

When I type **npm install --save solc** in the comment prompt on the mac, it's like [image: this]

And after these a package is downloaded. I am a windows user and I tried to do this. I have an error like

```
C:\Users\senem\Desktop\inbox>npm install --save solc
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file C:\Users\senem\Desktop\inbox\package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\senem\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-04T23_05_05_768Z-debug.log
```

[image: this]

I can't download it because I don't know which package it is. Is there anyone who can help? How can I download this or how can I solve this error?

Comment: The error says it failed to parse `C:\Users\senem\Desktop\inbox\package.json` on the Windows computer. Can you share this file (from the windows systeom)? ... Also one more thing that comes to my mind is the `\n` and `\r\n` incompatibility between Windows and Unix.